# Magic braces in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote some function to add some polylines to Excel sheet. Then I've discovered strange braces behavior.
I declare and define points array as this:

```
Dim points As Variant
Dim sh As Shape

points = Array(Array(10.5, 10.5), Array(20.4, 20.4), Array(5.1, 30.3), Array(10.5, 10.5))

' These both do not work and I get error about wrong type (error 1004) in 2007
' and application defined error 1004 on 2010:

ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPolyline points
Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPolyline(points)

' These work fine:

ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPolyline (points)
Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPolyline((points))
```

What is the strange magic of VBA braces?

Tested in 2007 and 2010 versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The additional parentheses around `points` cause the argument to be [evaluated as an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10262247/11683) and consequently be passed `ByVal`.

The act of evaluating an array can change exactly how the data is packed inside the `Variant` that contains it (e.g. see [VBA: Remove duplicates fails when columns array is passed using a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39104653/11683) as an example), and if the called procedure is not very lenient about what types of arrays it can accept (which it should be), then it will raise an error.

In your case I am actually surprised that passing an evaluated `(points)` even works, because the documentation mentions that a 2D array of `Single`s is expected, and `Array(Array(...), Array(...), ...)` is a jagged array as opposed to a 2D array. It would appear `AddPolyline` is written to cope with jagged arrays too, but it only recognizes them when the Variant containing the array has a particular set of flags in it which evaluating seems to produce (e.g. it might be that the [presence or absence of `VT_BYREF`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31637346/11683) trips its flag comparison so it fails to recognize the passed array as supported).

I would call it a bug in `AddPolyline`, and I would explicitly define and fill a 2D array of `Single` to avoid it:

```
Dim points(1 To 4, 1 To 2) As Single
points(1, 1) = 10.5: points(1, 2) = 10.5
points(2, 1) = 20.4: points(2, 2) = 20.4
points(3, 1) = 5.1: points(3, 2) = 30.3
points(4, 1) = 10.5: points(4, 2) = 10.5
```

Comment: Thanks for answer and for clarification. Finally I will do it the way you suggest because the source of coordinates will be easly parseable text file.