# why is a string variable strVar not the same as cStr(strVar)?

Tags: vba

Why does a **string variable** need to be enclosed in a cStr() conversion to be used as a key string for the CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders collection?

Demonstration of this absurdity(?):

```
Sub sdfgdfsg()
    Const strCon_SpecialFolderName As String = "MyDocuments"
    Dim strVar_SpecialFolderName As String
    strVar_SpecialFolderName = "MyDocuments"
    
    Debug.Print CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(strCon_SpecialFolderName) ' CORRECT
    Debug.Print CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(strVar_SpecialFolderName) ' WRONG! (it returns the Desktop path instead)
    Debug.Print CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(CStr(strVar_SpecialFolderName)) ' CORRECT
    Debug.Print CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("MyDocuments") ' CORRECT
End Sub
```

I read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/item-method-visual-basic-for-applications) about the index argument for a collection without finding an answer.

Comment: `Dim strVar_SpecialFolderName As Variant` fixes it, which does not really go well with the `CStr` solution. It's not indexing though, it's a method call. It was designed for scripting languages in the first place so it's no wonder it works with Variant, but then why would `CStr` also fix it? Probably has something to do with exactly how VBA marshals values on late bound calls.

Comment: You can also solve the issue using `Debug.Print CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders((strVar_SpecialFolderName))`. It looks, placing the string between a new set of parenthesis, it evaluates it as it should. I (also) read about conversion to `Variant`, but I did not see any Microsoft statement on the issue... I used this way when passing the string variable to a function. In such a case, passing it `ByValue` also solves the problem.

Comment: @FaneDuru Ah, another instance of https://stackoverflow.com/q/52686198/11683 then...

Comment: @GSerg  Yup.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [WScript library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aew9yb99(v=vs.85)) was designed to be used from scripting languages such as VBScript which use `Variant`s. The [`SpecialFolders.Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/yzefkb42(v=vs.85)) that you are calling expects a Variant containing a string, too.

The result you are seeing appears to come from the fact that the library is not able to read the Variant-wrapped string value VB passes, and does something wrong instead. You can achieve the same result with

```vb
Dim strVar_SpecialFolderName As String
strVar_SpecialFolderName = vbNullString

'Returns C:\Users\Public\Desktop
Debug.Print CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(strVar_SpecialFolderName)
```

For reasons I don't fully understand, there sometimes is a problem with passing Variant-wrapped data from VBA to an external object. I speculate that it may have something to do with the [presence or absence of the `VT_BYREF` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31637346/11683) in the Variant that VB(A) produces, and it produces it differently for constants, local variables and temporaries.

I believe this to be a problem on the receiving side, not in VBA.

Workarounds include:

- Declaring the variable as `Variant` to begin with:

  ```vb
  Dim strVar_SpecialFolderName As Variant
  strVar_SpecialFolderName = "MyDocuments"

  Debug.Print CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(strVar_SpecialFolderName)
  ```
- [Forcing an evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52686311/11683) which turns the local variable into a temporary (that is what your `CStr` does, too) which apparently changes how VB packs it into a Variant:

  ```vb
  Dim strVar_SpecialFolderName As String
  strVar_SpecialFolderName = "MyDocuments"

  Debug.Print CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders((strVar_SpecialFolderName))
  ```

Comment: Thanks @GSerg.  In your linked documentation I read "for the [...] SpecialFolders collections, index is a string" so I can't even know in advance that there will be a string to variant conversion.   Would you recommend using (one) workaround preventively each time we pass a string variable to an (any) external object wanting a string or variant?

Comment: @6diegodiego9 I wouldn't actually. If it's indeed a string, there is no VT_BYREF in the first place. And if it's a Variant, the receiving side must be able to cope with both, and it's a bug if it doesn't. So use as needed, and leave a comment when you do, because it's not a "normal" way of calling it

Comment: Nice explanation(s) on a the described hypothesis and facts. Which looks bo be sustained by solid logic...